# AngularJS list not updating when changes are made

Tags: html, angularjs

I think I know why the list isn't changing so this question is probably more "how can I do this in a way that 2 way binding will work?"

I have this view:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-light">
        <thead>
            <tr class="uppercase">
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'name'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Name
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'name' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'name' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'description'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Description
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'description' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'description' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'address1'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Address 1
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address1' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address1' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'address2'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Address 2
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address2' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address2' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'address3'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Address 3
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address3' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address3' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'address4'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Address 4
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address4' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'address4' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <a href="" ng-click="controller.predicate = 'postCode'; controller.reverse = !controller.reverse">
                        Post code
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'postCode' && !controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="controller.predicate == 'postCode' && controller.reverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
                    </a>
                </th>
                <th class="actions">

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="center in controller.centers.data | orderBy: controller.predicate:controller.reverse | filter: controller.filter | itemsPerPage : controller.pageSize" ng-click="controller.select($index)">
                <td>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="controller.isSelected($index)" />
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.description }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.address1 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.address2 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.address3 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.address4 }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ center.postCode }}
                </td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="controller.add($event, $index)" ng-if="!controller.contains(controller.userCenters, center)">
                        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="controller.remove($event, $index)" ng-if="controller.contains(controller.userCenters, center)">
                        <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

(truncated for brevity)

Now, you can see that the action buttons are shown depending on a function. This function checks the centers and sees if they are a part of the users centers. If they are, then the remove button is shown, if they are not, then the add button is shown.
The controller for that looks like this:

```
.controller('UserCentersController', ['$stateParams', 'ArrayService', 'CenterService', 'toastr', 'centers', 'userCenters', function ($stateParams, arrayService, service, toastr, centers, userCenters) {

    var self = this;

    // Get our user Id
    var userId = $stateParams.userId;

    // Assign our centers
    self.centers = centers;
    self.userCenters = userCenters;
    self.selected = [];

    // Create our page sizes array
    self.pageSizes = [10, 20, 50, 100];

    // For filtering and sorting the table
    self.pageSize = self.pageSizes[0];
    self.predicate = 'name';
    self.reverse = false;
    self.filter = '';

    console.log(centers);

    // Select method
    self.select = function (index) {

        // Get our index
        var i = self.selected.indexOf(index);

        // If our index is in our array
        if (i > -1) {

            // Remove from our array
            self.selected.splice(i, 1);

            // Else, our index is not in our array
        } else {

            // Add our index to our array
            self.selected.push(index);
        }
    };

    // Check to see if the row is selected
    self.isSelected = function (index) {

        // If our item is in our array, return true
        return (self.selected.indexOf(index) > -1);
    };

    // Function to check if a center is in an array
    self.contains = function (array, center) {

        // Check to see if our center is in the array
        return arrayService.indexOf(center) > -1 ? true : false;
    };

    // Adds the current center to the users list
    self.add = function (e, index) {

        // Stop propagation
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log(index);

        // If we have an index
        if (typeof index !== 'undefined') {

            // Get our center
            var center = self.centers.data[index];

            console.log(center);

            // Make our call
            //var save = service.addToUser(center, userId);

            // Push to our user centers if it's not already there
            arrayService.modify(self.userCenters.data, center);

            console.log(self.userCenters.data);
        }
    };    
}]);
```

Now, when add is pressed, the center is added to the user centers (by pushing the current center to the userCenters array). I would expect that when that is done, the view would update and the add button would be replaced with the remove button, but it is not.

I think this is because the **self.centers.data** array is not changed, so the view stays the same. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: It might be that, can you show how you get `self.userCenters` and what the `arrayService.modify` is doing?

Comment: self.userCenters is just pulled back from the API.
arrayService.modify is a service I wrote that will add / remove items from an array depending on whether it exists in the passed array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $scope.$watch on the self.centers.data like this one :

```
$scope.$watch('self.userCenters.data',function(newValue,oldValue){

   if(!newValue)return;
   if(newValue==oldValue)return;
   if(!$scope.$$phase){
      $scope.$apply();
   }

});
```

Comment: I would prefer not to use a watch in the controller if possible

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing what you want.
1) your list of centers is controlled by the service, and the variable in the controller is just a reference to the array on the service. Your call to the service can be just `arrayService.modify(center);` since the service already knows the array.

2) you have two separate lists of centers, one in the service and other in the controller. And when you update the one in the service, you need to update the one in the controller:

```
arrayService.modify(self.userCenters.data, center);
self.userCenters.data = angular.copy(arrayService.getCenters());
```

Since I don't know how you coded your service, I don't know which one is better in your case, but I prefer option 1.

Comment: Nah, I think you are a little confused as to what is happening. self.centers is the main array, self.userCenters is what centers are assigned to the user. When you press the add button, the self.center which is selected (or clicked) is added to self.userCenters. The buttons are displayed depending whether or not the current center is in the self.userCenters array.

Comment: I think the solution is to create a new array, this new array will contain all the centers, but have a new property called added which I will set to true or false and when the button is clicked I will modify that array instead which should cause it to update the view

Comment: Anyway, have your service do all the work and keep both center arrays and have the controller just referencing the arrays in the service. In that way, when you change the array in the service it will be automatically updated in the controller.